# Popover rotation

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have problem with popover. What I did were:

1. Rotate my application from landscape to portrait
2. Show MasterViewController in Popup
3. Rotate Back To Landscape

Note:
masterViewController = View in the left side of splitViewController
detailViewController = View in the right side of splitViewController

At the end of rotation, masterViewController is shift down and now I have blank space between navigation & viewController. (for image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/vriel/5470798582/). This problem is not exist when I destroy the popover before the rotation (by tapping outside popover window).

In my detailViewController, I have the following code:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {  
    if (popover && popover.popoverVisible) [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];}

-(void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc {
    UIBarButtonItem* button = [UIBarButtonItem allocinitWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showPopover:)];
}

-(void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:  (UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
    if (self.navigationItem) [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
}


-(void)showPopover:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController* c = (UINavigationController*)[self getApplicationDelegateObject:@selector(masterViewController)];
    if (c) {  
        if (!popover) {
            popover = [UIPopoverController allocinitWithContentViewController:c];
        } else {
            popover.contentViewController = c;
        }
        if (popover) {
            [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: In that case you can hook with the UIViewController's - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration and dismiss the popover view before the rotation starts?

Comment: Hi Nevin, I already did that and yet the problem still exist. I still do not understand where the blank space come from :-(. I might be wrong about popover causing all of this. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally found where the problem is

**previously:**
Before I create my own bar button item to handle rotation. In fact, I should not worry about the popover because apple already take care of it

```
-(void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc {

UIBarButtonItem* button = [UIBarButtonItem allocinitWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showPopover:)];
}
```

**correct one:**

```
-(void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc {
if (self.navigationItem) [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:NO];
}
```